# Hibernate one-to-one mapping error

Tags: hibernate, key, shared, cascade, one-to-one

I am using one-to-one mapping with shared primary key.

My mappings are something like -

```
<class name="EmployeeDetails" table="EMPLOYEE_DETAILS" >
    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/> 
    <id name="employeeId" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="EMPLOYEE_ID" precision="12" scale="0" />
        <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">employee</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="score" type="java.math.BigDecimal" update="true">
        <column name="SCORE" />
    </property>
    <one-to-one name="employee" class="Employee" constrained="true"/>
</class>
```

and in Employee.hbm.xml I have

```
    <one-to-one name="employeeDetails" class="EmployeeDetails" cascade="all,delete-orphan"></one-to-one>
```

I just set `employee.setEmployeeDetails(new EmployeeDetails(score));`
and try to save employee. 
The query fired is update query but no record is present in EMPLOYEE_DETAILS table. I want it to be inserted instead. How can I achieve this? If I use cascade cascade="save-update" I don't get any error. If I use cascade="save-update" I am getting an error `No row with the given identifier exists`
But both times it only fires update query.

Comment: you may try to compare with http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue like below -

```
        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails= employee.getEmployeeDetails();

        if(employeeDetails!= null){
            employeeDetails.setScore(statusVO.getScore());
        }
        else {
            employeeDetails = new EmployeeDetails(statusVO.getScore());
            employeeDetails.setEmployee(employee);
        }
        employeeDetailsService.saveOrUpdate(employeeDetails);
```

The key was that when employeeDetails exists in db (and so in Employee object) then just update attributes and when it does not only set employee object and hibernate will take care of inserting with correct id picked up from employee object.